# Error in starting spring boot application, facing issues related Hikari Pool

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, hikaricp

I have multimodule spring boot project.

If I make any changes to application.yml file and run the app for the first time, Application starts successfully.
But after that I am facing this issue -

```
{
  "@timestamp" : "2021-01-10T20:31:04.279+05:30",
  "message" : "HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=1, idle=9, waiting=0)",
  "logger_name" : "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool",
  "thread_name" : "HikariPool-1 housekeeper",
  "level" : "DEBUG"
}
{
  "@timestamp" : "2021-01-10T20:31:04.279+05:30",
  "message" : "HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.",
  "logger_name" : "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool",
  "thread_name" : "HikariPool-1 housekeeper",
  "level" : "DEBUG"
}
{
  "@timestamp" : "2021-01-10T20:31:34.281+05:30",
  "message" : "HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=1, idle=9, waiting=0)",
  "logger_name" : "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool",
  "thread_name" : "HikariPool-1 housekeeper",
  "level" : "DEBUG"
}
{
  "@timestamp" : "2021-01-10T20:31:34.281+05:30",
  "message" : "HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.",
  "logger_name" : "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool",
  "thread_name" : "HikariPool-1 housekeeper",
  "level" : "DEBUG"
}
{
  "@timestamp" : "2021-01-10T20:32:04.283+05:30",
  "message" : "HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=1, idle=9, waiting=0)",
  "logger_name" : "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool",
  "thread_name" : "HikariPool-1 housekeeper",
  "level" : "DEBUG"
}
{
  "@timestamp" : "2021-01-10T20:32:04.283+05:30",
  "message" : "HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.",
  "logger_name" : "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool",
  "thread_name" : "HikariPool-1 housekeeper",
  "level" : "DEBUG"
}
{
  "@timestamp" : "2021-01-10T20:32:34.284+05:30",
  "message" : "HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=1, idle=9, waiting=0)",
  "logger_name" : "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool",
  "thread_name" : "HikariPool-1 housekeeper",
  "level" : "DEBUG"
}
{
  "@timestamp" : "2021-01-10T20:32:34.284+05:30",
  "message" : "HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.",
  "logger_name" : "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool",
  "thread_name" : "HikariPool-1 housekeeper",
  "level" : "DEBUG"
}
{
  "@timestamp" : "2021-01-10T20:33:04.284+05:30",
  "message" : "HikariPool-1 - Pool stats (total=10, active=1, idle=9, waiting=0)",
  "logger_name" : "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool",
  "thread_name" : "HikariPool-1 housekeeper",
  "level" : "DEBUG"
}
{
  "@timestamp" : "2021-01-10T20:33:04.284+05:30",
  "message" : "HikariPool-1 - Fill pool skipped, pool is at sufficient level.",
  "logger_name" : "com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool",
  "thread_name" : "HikariPool-1 housekeeper",
  "level" : "DEBUG"
}
{
  "@timestamp" : "2021-01-10T21:15:16.774+05:30",
  "message" : "Application run failed",
  "logger_name" : "org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication",
  "thread_name" : "main",
  "level" : "ERROR",
  "stack_trace" : "org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jdbcConverter' parameter 4; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDialect' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect]: Factory method 'jdbcDialect' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30001ms.\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:797)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:538)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)\r\n\tat org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:143)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)\r\n\tat sample_service.Application.main(Application.java:11)\r\nCaused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDialect' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect]: Factory method 'jdbcDialect' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30001ms.\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:635)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1336)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1176)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1307)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1227)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:884)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:788)\r\n\t... 20 common frames omitted\r\nCaused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect]: Factory method 'jdbcDialect' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30001ms.\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650)\r\n\t... 34 common frames omitted\r\nCaused by: org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30001ms.\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:82)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:324)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver$DefaultDialectProvider.getDialect(DialectResolver.java:106)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver.lambda$getDialect$0(DialectResolver.java:76)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.tryAdvance(ArrayList.java:1602)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:150)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:543)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.DialectResolver.getDialect(DialectResolver.java:78)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.AbstractJdbcConfiguration.jdbcDialect(AbstractJdbcConfiguration.java:144)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)\r\n\tat org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)\r\n\t... 35 common frames omitted\r\nCaused by: java.sql.SQLTransientConnectionException: HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30001ms.\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createTimeoutException(HikariPool.java:695)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:197)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.getConnection(HikariPool.java:162)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:128)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116)\r\n\tat org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:79)\r\n\t... 54 common frames omitted\r\n",
  "parameters" : "[{\"persistentEntities\":[],\"namingStrategy\":{\"schema\":\"\"},\"forceQuote\":true,\"managedTypes\":[]}, \"jdbcMappingContext\"]",
  "execution_time_for_repository_in_ms" : "1"
}
```

Its not going ahead, just receiving the same logs as above.

Here is my Parent pom.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>lib/logging</module>
        <module>lib/security</module>
        <module>lib/exception</module>
        <module>backend-starter</module>
        <module>lib/api-docs</module>
        <module>lib/utility</module>
        <module>lib/notification</module>
        <module>lib/file-handler</module>
        <module>application/sample-service</module>
    </modules>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from utility.repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Spring boot Multi Module Project</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Multi Module Project</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <azure.version>2.2.1</azure.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR8</spring-cloud.version>
        <app.version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</app.version>
        <springfox-swagger2.version>3.0.0</springfox-swagger2.version>
        <sqlserver.version>7.4.1.jre8</sqlserver.version>
        <jsonwebtoken.version>0.10.7</jsonwebtoken.version>
        <unirest.version>3.3.00</unirest.version>
        <maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <ai-spring-boot-starter.version>2.6.2</ai-spring-boot-starter.version>
        <jansi.version>1.11</jansi.version>
        <logstash.version>6.4</logstash.version>
        <ai-logging-logback.version>2.6.1</ai-logging-logback.version>
        <syntax-highlighter.version>1.0.3</syntax-highlighter.version>
        <mteric-collector.version>2.3.5</mteric-collector.version>
    </properties>
    

    <dependencies>
        
        <!-- Spring boot starter dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        
        
        <!-- provide facility to interact with underlying database -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${sqlserver.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- provide framework for testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-spring-boot-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${azure.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    

</project>
```

Here is application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: sample-service
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://servername.database.windows.net:1433;database=example;user=idas@exampledatabase;password=@asds;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
    driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    

  jpa:
    hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
    hibernate.ddl-auto: create-drop
    show-sql: true
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
  autoconfigure:
    exclude:
      - org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration
      - org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration


server:
  port: 8080
  servlet:
    session:
      cookie:
        http-only: true
        secure: true

app:
  version: 1.0.0
  security:
    enabled: true
  swagger:
    enable-auth: false
    title: Sample Service
    desc: Helps to interact with Backend
    version: v1
    path-mapping: /
    contact:
      name: Backend Team
      email: test@test.com
      url: ""
    license: null
    license-uri: null
```

Comment: What does _"Its not going ahead"_ mean? Regarding _"I am facing this issue"_ - what is the issue? Those are debug messages you are showing us, not error messages. Can you [edit] your question to clarify?

Comment: You have `url: jdbc:sqlserver://servername.database.windows.net:1433` is your DB server's name really `servername.database.windows.net`?

Comment: @andrewjames yes I changed the URL from some other name to servername just to share here

Comment: Understood. If you make changes like that, it helps if you mention them in the question. After your edits, now I can see a specific error for you to investigate: `Failed to obtain JDBC Connection`.